# How to fix bootchart error

Tags: bootchart

bootchart throws this error message.

```
sudo  pybootchartgui
No path given, trying /var/log/bootchart.tgz  
warning: path '/var/log/bootchart.tgz' does not exist, ignoring.
Parse error: empty state: '/var/log/bootchart.tgz' does not contain a valid bootchart
```

Answer (score 5):

In my version of ubuntu (12.04) `bootchart` creates a different log file every time the computer boots, this goes into the directory `/var/log/bootstrap`. Though, `bootstartgui` looks by default to the file `/var/log/bootchart.tgz` which does not exist.

In 12.04, if you install `bootchart` properly, you automatically get an image file of the boot graph representation, so you do not need to run `bootstartgui`.

In fact, it is enough to run (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>):

```
nautilus /var/log/bootchart
```

then double click on the image that contains the date and time that you are interested in.

If you want to delete useless logs and save space, you can start nautilus with sudo from the commandline: Type (Alt+Ctrl+T) and then:

```
gksu nautilus /var/log/bootchart
```

This will give you a window where you can also delete files. Be very cautious not to delete anything on another folder!

Answer (score 4):

That error seems to be normal when you installed `pybootchartgui` (is for viewing bootcharts) but did not install package `bootchart` (this makes the bootchart) ([source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pybootchartgui/+bug/565970)).

`pybootchartgui` is also used to view other machine's bootchart so `bootchart` is not a dependency of this package.

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu 15.04 and later**

The boot chart will appear in **/run/log/bootchart*.svg** with a time stamp in the name.