# bootchart 'No path given' error

Tags: boot, bootchart

I already installed pybootchartgui and boot chart in Ubuntu 16.04. After running

```
sudo pybootchartgui
```

or

```
sudo bootchart
```

this is the result:

```
No path given, trying /var/log/bootchart.tgz  
warning: path '/var/log/bootchart.tgz' does not exist, ignoring.
Parse error: empty state: '/var/log/bootchart.tgz' does not contain a valid bootchar
```

There is a duplicate question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58463/how-to-fix-bootchart-error). It is is very old and the answers provided doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Since `systemd` came in, many old tools are now deprecated. `bootchart` is one of those. To have a graphic representation of your boot you can use the internal tools without needing to install anything else.

Use

```
systemd-analyze plot > ~/plot.svg
```

and you will have the file `plot.svg` ready in your home.

Please be sure to always follow guides and instructions for the correct version of Ubuntu that you have!