# Why does my computer take so long to boot?

Tags: boot

My computer has a Asus x99 E WS mobo, with intel i7-6850K processor and ubuntu 14.04 installed on a SSD. Yet the boot time is more than 30s which seems too high for such a powerful machine.

Running bootchart (image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfDV1.png)) shows that the system is idle for the first 10 seconds(except for some kworkers). How do I fix this?

EDIT: This machine has 4 GPUs, does it have anything to do with the slow boot time?

Comment: 30 seconds for a boot 14.04 is actually rather good.

Boot time has been greatly improved in subsequent versions, tough (at least in my experience with a Dell with SSD and Nvidia). Try to install 16.04; it will probably get much better. Remember that, on 16.04, [bootchart will be deprecated](http://askubuntu.com/a/788886/29595).

Comment: And no process uses the CPU, or the disk, apparently.

Comment: @dadexix86 I tried 16.04 too, I am facing the same problem. I have another machine running 14.04 which is pretty fast (~ 14s,  lower specs).

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: @dadexix86 32GB

Comment: So it's not a problem of RAM. But with 16.04 you have the same problem? That's weird, because `init` should not be there anymore :S Is it not that you started with `upstart` when you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to diagnose/fix very slow boot on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030867/how-to-diagnose-fix-very-slow-boot-on-ubuntu-18-04)